# Which is Best: First Log then do the Operation OR First do the Operation then Log it?

Tags: logging, coldfusion, coding-style

Actuall recently I have some requirement in which I will send some pdfs via email on a regular basis to a printing media to print
the pdfs.At the same time I also need to log these details in a table. Logging is very much important in this case as we generate 
monthly reports on the basis of these logs.

Now my question is if I will mail the files first using cfmail , but if later the db fails to log it will be a problem.
Otherwise If I log it first , but after that if the mail server fails then that will a big problem again.

So what I should do in this case?

Comment: Consider using your mailsent log as a source of data.

Answer (score 8):

Since sending pdfs via email is an important operation for you, 
I'd suggest following approach:

- Log **before** operation
- Log **after** succesful operation
- Log **in case of failure**

Thanks to this you will be informed in every case.